# How to fix "relation "pg_range" does not exist" in postgresql nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql, express

I have error on my host, that is 100% related with PostgreSQL version.

PostgreSQL version: 8.4.20

This is my error:

```
    { error: relation "pg_range" does not exist
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/home/freiqdsy/nodevenv/public_html/agents.freightmasters.az/10/lib/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
    at Parser.handlePacket (/home/freiqdsy/nodevenv/public_html/agents.freightmasters.az/10/lib/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (/home/freiqdsy/nodevenv/public_html/agents.freightmasters.az/10/lib/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
    at Socket.stream.on (/home/freiqdsy/nodevenv/public_html/agents.freightmasters.az/10/lib/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
  length: 100,
  name: 'error',
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42P01',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: '145',
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'parse_relation.c',
  line: '894',
  routine: 'parserOpenTable' }
```

I found the information that this error is cause the PostgreSQL version is under 9.0. How can I fix this and make it work on my PostgreSQL version?

[Here is the exact code that I am using](https://medium.com/@rachealkuranchie/node-js-authentication-with-postgresql-sequelize-and-express-js-20ae773da4c9)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Postgres 8.4 is long dead and forgotten. You should upgrade to a recent version (14,15) instead of trying to stick with that ancient version

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using namecheap's shared hosting, so its impossible

Comment: Move to a different hosting provider, this is crazy to offer such an outdated version.

Comment: `pg_range` deals with `range` types and they are not introduced until 9.2(not 9.0), so there is no way you are getting this to work with  8.4.